# Python jupyter file not found in iCloud error

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm rather new to Python (and Jupyter notebook), so this might be a pretty elementary question.

I'm currently trying to import data from a CSV file using pandas, but I keep getting the file not found error.
I have gone through a few similar questions on Stack Overflow, but I still couldn't fix it.

df1=pd.read_csv("../Documents/septemberoctober2017jikkendata/XViewerData/20171016/slit/slithalfopen.csv")

The error I get is

> FileNotFoundError: File
>   b'../Documents/septemberoctober2017jikkendata/XViewerData/20171016/slit/slithalfopen.csv'
>   does not exist

The document info states that the file is kept in the iCloud drive. Is that the reason for the error?

[image]

Comment: Where is the notebook running? Python isn't lying to you. You've accessed a path relative to where you started Jupyter

Comment: Perhaps you should do something like `/iCloud/Documents/`... Give it an absolute path

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new at Jupyter so I don't really understand the question. All I did was just type in "jupyter notebook" on the terminal command line. Typing in the absolute path didn't work either..

Comment: 1) `/iCloud` isn't a location on the disk, so don't actually use that 2) whatever directory you ran that command in needs to be within the Documents folder of iCloud... Hence the `../`

Comment: ICloud will only be a problem if you haven't downloaded the file yet. Python won't do that for you

Comment: Moving the documents from iCloud back to Mac and then running the jupyter notebook directly where the csv file was worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Jupyter will execute with a data directory of the current location where you started the notebook.

For example, if you are in your `~/Downloads` folder, then `../Documents` would go to searching in your local Documents. Make sure you start the command in the necessary directory if you are using relative paths.

Alternatively, use an absolute path

I'm not sure where iCloud files are stored, but it wouldn't hurt to verify that the file exists elsewhere on disk and you aren't just seeing me Tara about it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://osxdaily.com/2017/11/16/access-icloud-drive-command-line-mac/) is an OSX Daily article on how to access iCloud from the command line, which is what you will need to do. In short, you will need to prepend references to any folders in iCloud with `~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/`